# Ionic retry post information policy/strategy

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

The app is used for delivering packages, everytime a package is delivered it must post information to the server ASAP.

Since sometimes the postman does not have internet connection there is some type of cache which saves the information and every 1 second try to send the information.

Of course, this is not a good idea, because sometimes the visit fails in server and the phone consumes a lot of battery and data usage because it retry forever.

How can I implement a policy or strategy to solve this problem?

My actual code

```
$interval(function () {
            $this.syncup();
        }, 1000);


this.syncup = function () {
    $this.lastSync  = $filter('date')(new Date(), "mediumTime");
    $this.promises = $this.promises || [];
    if ($this.NotSentOperations() && $this.NotSentOperations().length && authenticationService.getToken()) {
        angular.forEach($this.NotSentOperations(), function (operation, key) {
            if (!$this.promises[operation.tarea]) {
                    $this.promises[operation.tarea] = $http.post(CONFIG.URL_POST_OPERATION, operation, {timeout: 300000})
                            .then(
                                    function (res) {
                                        $this.removeOperationNotSend($this.NotSentOperations().indexOf(operation));
                                    },
                                    function (error) {
                                        if (error.status === 409)
                                            $this.removeOperationNotSend($this.NotSentOperations().indexOf(operation));
                                    }
                            )
                            .finally(function () {
                                $this.promises[operation.tarea] = null; 
                            });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: sorry my answer is for Angular 5 / Ionic 3+ and your code might be using angularjs ionic 1?

Answer (score 0):

Yes sounds like having interval and calling a method every 1s is sub optimal. I would recommend using "network monitor" approach. I did that a while ago and used in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51395617/native-ionic-network-status-doesnt-work-on-my-code/51396586#51396586)

Basic idea is to "know" whether your code runs on cordova or web app (pwa), then use relevant plugin or browser method and detect when app changes online/offline state. Then do sync during offline to online state change. **This is for Angular 5 / Ionic 3 as example:**

```
  // REQUIRED IMPORTS:
  import { Network } from "@ionic-native/network";
  import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

  // DETECT DEVICE/BROWSER:
  this.appIsOnDevice = !this.platform.url().startsWith('http');

  // INIT NETWORK MONITOR:
  initNetworkMonitor() {
    // check if we are on device or if its a browser
    if (this.appIsOnDevice) {
      // watch network for a disconnect
      this.disconnectSubscription = this.network
        .onDisconnect()
        .subscribe(() => {
          console.log("network disconnected:(");
          // do alert here
        });
      // watch network for a connection
      this.connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
        console.log("network connected!");
        // app got back online, do logic here
        if (this.network.type === "wifi") {
          console.log("we got a wifi connection, woohoo!");
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.browserOffline = Observable.fromEvent(window, "offline").subscribe(
        () => {
          // go offline logic here
        }
      );
      this.browserOnline = Observable.fromEvent(window, "online").subscribe(
        () => {
          // go back online
        }
      );
    }
  }
```